# Transfer data to join table: Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, migration

I have a rails model `Game` and another model `Player`. Currently, the data for players assigned to a game was being stored in an array (of player ids) in the `games` table.

I'm trying to create a join table to connect games and I created a `HABTM` join table `games_players` and then I'm trying to run a migration to do transfer the data before running another migration to delete the `players` array from the `games` table.

My code to transfer the data is as follows:

```
games = Game.all
games.each do |g|
  game = g
  games.players.each do |p|
    game.players << p
  end
end
```

But it doesn't save the data at all in the join table rather it goes ahead with deleting the array column in the `games` table. How can I transfer all this data to the new join table before deleting the attribute?

Added associations for clarification:

```
class GamesPlayers < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :game, inverse_of: :games_players
  belongs_to :player, inverse_of: :games_players
end

class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :games_players, inverse_of: :game
  has_many :players, through: :game_players
end

class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :games_players, inverse_of: :player
  has_many :games, through: :games_players
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `Game#player_ids` returns an array of existing `Player` `id` 
integers, you should be able to do:

```
Game.find_each do |game|
  game.player_ids.each do |player_id|
    game.games_players.create!(player_id: player_id)
  end
end
```

But this code implies that you have not yet defined the relation `has_many :players, through: :games_players` on the `Game` model because it uses `player_ids` as the attribute reader for the column `games.player_ids`

Comment: Okay so this works perfectly when I change my model name to `GamesPlayer` because of the way rails pluralizes the models I guess. I'm selecting this as the correct answer as it answers the original question but I'm not sure if the way I'm naming the model is the best way to do so